# Random latency on a wireless LAN

Tags: network-core, latency

I'm facing a weird situation. Office LAN configuration is :

- A Netgear router as the main router
- An Ubuntu PC with UniFi controller software
- 10 UniFi APs

At anytime, the latency between a computer and the main router using a wired connection is 0.300 ms and 0.400 ms. Using Wi-Fi, the latency can vary from 1 ms to 1000 ms and, eventually, a timeout. If at the exact same time, I check the latency using a wired computer, it's still 0.300ms.

I checked the bandwidth and it's always low. I'm assuming a device on the network is creating latency. I installed ntop to monitor the network, but I found nothing obvious.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to discover what is on the airwaves. It sounds like you are experiencing wireless interference.

You can hire a company to come in and do a wireless site survey. This will give you information about what is going on in the airwaves, how many WAPs are necessary, where the best  WAP placements are, how to adjust the radio power and channels for best performance, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some higher-end wireless equipment and do a spectral scan of your Wi-Fi frequency range to select best frequency for your Wi-Fi router. Ubiquiti, MikroTik, and few other manufacturers of Wi-Fi gear have such an ability (even SOHO routers). They're not very expensive and quite powerful, also providing a toolkit to inspect what's happening to your network (wired and wireless).

I bet when you experience high pings on Wi-Fi, your CCQ drops to a low %. This can be caused by a number of factors, but mostly by interference from nearby devices operating on same or nearby channel.

Also, remember that wireless communication is two-way thing; the interference may affect AP as much as client.